# Separating two strings without a separating character

Tags: data-structures, strings

Say you need to write a function such that you have string a and string b.
The function argument is a concatenation of string a and string b.
The function prints string a and string b separately. I'll explain.

For example one can think of a naive solution such that 'x' will be a separator character and so if we want to print "hello world" for example we create a function that prints everything as string a until it encounters an 'x' char and than it knows that string b is starting.
So our argument will be something like:

void separateString("helloxworld");

But this eliminates the option of using 'x' as a char in our String.

I am sure that there is a simple solution to this that I am not getting.

Not looking for code, just your idea. The code will be easy to implement.

Thanks

Comment: Pass the length of the first string?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_code ​ ​

Answer (score 3):

Just an extended note for the "quoting" techniques:

You can also pick one character of the alphabet (e.g. $a$) and interpret it as a space and use $aa$ for $a$:

```
 hello world  -> helloaworld
 amazing spacing -> aamaazingaspaacing
```

However it is easy to see that this approach can lead to ambiguities:

```
 a are doubled -> aaaaare doubled 
                 --OK_DECODING   -> a are doubled
                 --WRONG_DECODING-> aa re doubled
```

These ambiguities can be avoided/ignored if we assume that the "special" character $a$ appears only in a well defined format and context.

Indeed this technique is still used for representing quotes or double quotes in well-known formats: e.g it is used for strings in the [CSV format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values): every string is double quoted and the double quotes in a string are "doubled".

```
 COLUMN 1 | COLUMN 2            | COLUMN 3
 42        | My name is "Nobody" | He said "To be or not to be" 
 43        | "Quote me"          | Charater " embedded
```

Are represented in CVS files as:

```
 42,"My name is ""Nobody""","He said ""To be or not to be"""
 43,"""Quote me""","Character "" embedded"
```

It is also used for single quotes in the SQL language:

```
 SELECT 'This is a quoted string: ''Hello world''!!!'
```

But more modern languages/formats usually prefer the escape technique (see Yuval's answer)

Answer (score 2):

The simplest approach is to use *escape characters*. Suppose that you want `x` to be your separator. To escape it, you use `\x` (that would mean `x`). To escape `\`, you use `\\` (that would mean `\`).